# Update and insert in for loop using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Can someone help me whats wrong in my code. I have below results object which I am setting it to an entity and trying to save or update in database.
My scenario is

1. To insert unique value according to month (07, 08)
2. 07 -> A, 99.44%
        B, 78.89%

   08 -> A, 99.31%

   `Object [] results = [[A, 07, 99.44%],
                                [B, 07, 78.89%],
                                [A, 08, 99.31%]];`

   ```
       for (Object[] info : results) {
       Test testObj = new testObj();
       if (info[0].toString().equals("A")) {   
           testObj.setMon(info[1].toString());
           testObj.setAPercent(info[2].toString());
           this.dao.save(testObj);
       }
       if (info[0].toString().equals("B")) {
           testObj.setMon(info[1].toString());
           testObj.setBPercent(info[2].toString());
           this.dao.save(testObj);
       }
   ```

> Hibernate: select errorcount0_.MONTH as MONTH1_18_0_,
>   errorcount0_.A_PERCENT as A_ERROR_PERCENT2_18_0_,
>   errorcount0_.B_PERCENT as B_ERROR_PERCENT3_18_0_ from
>   ERROR_COUNT_MONTHLY errorcount0_ where errorcount0_.MONTH=? Hibernate:
>   insert into ERROR_COUNT_MONTHLY (A_PERCENT, MONTH) values (?, ?)
>   Hibernate: select errorcount0_.MONTH as MONTH1_18_0_,
>   errorcount0_.A_PERCENT as A_ERROR_PERCENT2_18_0_,
>   errorcount0_.B_PERCENT as B_ERROR_PERCENT3_18_0_ from
>   ERROR_COUNT_MONTHLY errorcount0_ where errorcount0_.MONTH=? Hibernate:
>   update ERROR_COUNT_MONTHLY set A_PERCENT=?, B_PERCENT=? where MONTH=?
>   Hibernate: select errorcount0_.MONTH as MONTH1_18_0_,
>   errorcount0_.A_PERCENT as A_ERROR_PERCENT2_18_0_,
>   errorcount0_.B_PERCENT as B_ERROR_PERCENT3_18_0_ from
>   ERROR_COUNT_MONTHLY errorcount0_ where errorcount0_.MONTH=? Hibernate:
>   insert into ERROR_COUNT_MONTHLY (A_PERCENT, MONTH) values (?, ?)

```
I am getting output as below

MONTH   A_PERCENT   B_PERCENT
08      99.31%      78.89%
07      99.44%      78.89%


The actual output should look like
MONTH   A_PERCENT   B_PERCENT
08      99.31%      null
07      99.44%      78.89%
```

Comment: `if (info[0].toString().equals("B")) {` -> maybe it should be if `(info[1].toString().equals("B")) {`

Comment: @fg78nc Why? This is my object array Object [] results = [[A, 07, 99.44%],
                             [B, 07, 78.89%],
                             [A, 08, 99.31%]]

Comment: My bad, I did not quite understand your logic. Can you provide stack trace?

Comment: Where is the query returning the result?

Comment: @ujuluI have added in my question the query also. When I check in my db I get the result as MONTH   A_PERCENT   B_PERCENT
08      99.31%      78.89%
07      99.44%      78.89%